# How to force MSXML2 to load non UTF-8 encoded XML

Tags: xml, vba, character-encoding

I need to load an `ANSI` encoded XML file using MSXML2.DOMDocument, but that file does not contain the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>` line. The XML parser fails with `An invalid character was found in the text content` because XML data contains some national characters.

I tried to add a processing instructions like this but it does not do anything.

```
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

Dim PI
Set PI = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='windows-1250'")
xDoc.insertBefore PI, xDoc.childNodes.Item(0)

If xDoc.Load("C:\Test.xml") Then
    Debug.Print "Success"
Else
    Debug.Print xDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xDoc = Nothing
```

Is there a way to force the MSXML2 to use user-defined encoding BEFORE I call the .load method?

Comment: Are you saying your file has *no processing instruction at all*, or just that the PI has the wrong character set?

Comment: The XML file has no processing instruction at all. It starts with `<xml>` ends with `</xml>` and it is valid between these tags.

Comment: You could try reading the text content of the file, replacing the `<xml>` with your required processing instruction, and then use `xDoc.LoadXML` to load it from the modified version in memory (or write the modified version back to disk and use `Load`).

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I just noticed you came with the same idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this workaround: use `.LoadXML(strXML)` method instead.
You can add processing info this way:

```
Dim MyXML As String
Open "C:\Pass.XML" For Binary As #1
MyXML = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyXML
Close #1

MyXML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1250'?>" & vbCrLf & MyXML

If xDoc.loadXML(MyXML) Then
    Debug.Print "Success"
Else
    Debug.Print xDoc.parseError.reason
End If
```